# PHP function will not return mysqli query results

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems with this function.  I believe it may be in the way that I wrote my query. Both "id" and "$number" are integers.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, or a better way to write it.  Any help would be much apprecitiated.

```
<?php 

$number = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);



function getrecipeinfo($testing){

global $con;



$sqldescription = "SELECT category, eliquidname, image, contentnicpg, contentnicvg, description FROM vapetable where id = '{$number}' ;";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sqldescription);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();



     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){


        $eliquidtitle = $row['eliquidname'];
        $category = $row["description"];
        print $eliquidtitle;


             }

}

getrecipeinfo($testing);

?>
```

Comment: Pass `$number` not `$testing` to your function

Comment: You probably want to call getrecipeinfo($number); instead of getrecipeinfo($testing);

Comment: And your function never actually returns anything.

Comment: You have `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` **AND** `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`. Unless you have >1 row that is returned from the query, you will never get a result, as after the 1st call the internal pointer is moved forward and that will result in [`NULL if there are no more rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). So first, change the `$number`/`$testing` issue that has already been mentioned. Then second, remove the 1st `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: Oh yes, that is a typo.  But it still doesn't work.

Comment: ^ well you need to take it up with the answers given below. It seems like that bit them back.

Comment: @ Sean.  That worked.  Thank you!!! I am a bit of a newbie.  lol

Comment: @Sean yeah that one had me raise a brow there. should make that an answer, but that's your choice ;-)

Comment: did the question resolved? just noticed: you have pass non exists `$testing` with `getrecipeinfo($testing);` and inside the function you have not to use passed parameter your SQL-query looks like: `SELECT...where id = '{$number}' ;`. Here is `$number` instead of `$testing`. Ofc Sean's comment is very useful.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I typically wait for the standard [*Oh yes, that is a typo*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245221/php-function-will-not-return-mysqli-query-results#comment62019361_37245221) before posting answers to posters with less than 50 rep. To much wasted time in the past.

Comment: @Sean It was more than a typo. Plus, you know how things are around here nowadays. Some poor *"you know what"* is just going to come along, post an answer and make it their own. *sigh*. Well, if you won't, then I'll put one in but as a community wiki. There's no rep gain from that. It'll just be to  post it as a solution and maybe the OP will choose to mark it as solved. However, it would be better if you were to post one so you get the rep for it. After all, what you suggested was rather bigger than a mere typo ;-) Edit: But I see your point though about the less than 50 rep.

Answer (score 2):

A common, but simple mistake is to include a `->fetch_assoc();` call before/outside your `while()` loop -

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

In your case, since you are only returning 1 row from your query, that result is returned in the 1st `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`, and then the internal pointer is moved forward.

So when you get to `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){` there is no more results to return, as according to the docs -> [`Returns ... **NULL** if there are no more rows in resultset.`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

If you were returning more than 1 row, you would find your issue would be that it would return all rows, except for the 1st.

Comment: *hehe,* I was just about to post a community wiki and was about to press on the "Post Your Answer" button, which was at the same time you posted it *lol*, as I thought you weren't going to post an answer. Well there we go ;-) *Cheers* Sean.

Comment: I got called away for a moment, as my 11yr old wants to make the family dinner all on her own, so I missed seeing your last comment about creating a community wiki until after I posted as well. *Cheers* to you as well @Fred-ii-.

Comment: I take it everything's under control then ;-) *Cheers* and thanks. *buon appetito!*

Answer (score 0):

You should pass $number ( getrecipeinfo($number); ), i have a Mysqli Class for PHP i share my repository https://github.com/dev-lusaja/ezMysql